# Unable to SpyOn htpp.get method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Sample code:

```
if (!this.scope.popupHtmlTemplate) {
    this.$http.get("widgets/pinpointcomponent/browseLibraries/resources/browseLibrariesDialogModal.html")
    .success((data: any) => {
        console.log("Inside success"+data)
        if (data) {
            this.generateBootBoxDialog(data);
            this.scope.popupHtmlTemplate = data;
        }
    });
} else {
    this.generateBootBoxDialog(this.scope.popopupHtmlTemplate)
}
```

Testcase:

```
it("test expandLibrary case 3", () => {
    spyOn(http, "get");
    controller.showBrowseLibrariesDialog();
     expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Getting

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructorevaluating 'spyOn(http, "get")) error.

Any possible ways to write a testcase for this.

Comment: Sounds like `http` may not be defined in the scope of your test?  My next question would be, is `this.$http` a separate instance from `http`?  If so, you might have to set the spy on your current scope's instance of `http`, found presumably at `ths.$http`.  So more like, `spyOn(controller.$http, 'get')`.

Comment: Http is initialized with $http at the top.

Comment: It's important to share all contextual code. We weren't to assume that you'd defined http elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one you're spying on an undefined `http` service and not `$http`. To dig deeper, you want to be mocking those `$http` calls with `$httpBackend` from `ngMocks` instead.

[AngularJS: API: $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

This not only allows you to tell the test to expect an `$http` call methods like `$httpBackend.expectGET();` but it allows you to mock calls and force digests with `$httpBackend.flush();` and even mock the response.